# Не отрисовывается страница в angular 2

Tags: typescript

Разрабатываю в среде intelliJ IDEA Пишу на angular 2 
Самый простой пример.В файле пишу index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Angular 2 быстрый старт</title>
    <script src="https://github.jspm.io/jmcriffey/bower-traceur-runtime@0.0.87/traceur-runtime.js"></script>
    <script src="https://jspm.io/system@0.16.js"></script>
    <script src ="system.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.23/angular2.dev.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<app></app>
<script async>System.import('app');</script>
</body>
</html>
```

И файл app.ts

```
import{bootstrap, Component, View} from "angular2/angular2";
@Component({
    selector:'app'
})
@View({
    template:'<div>My first angular 2 App</div>'
})
class App{}

bootstrap(App);
```

И в `Index.html` есть `<app></app>` Мне кажется что нужно подключать. Но как?
Запускаю и пустая страница. Без ошибок.

Comment: а где вы подключаете _app.ts_?

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день.
По тому, что Вы описали, я попробовал разобраться, но сразу могу сказать, что здесь не до конца описана проблема, т.к. Вы не предоставили код из подключаемого Вами файла system.js
И так, по тому, что имеем:
1)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Angular 2 быстрый старт</title>

        <!--дальше подключаем стандартные скрипты-->
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/Rx.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/angular2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/http.min.js"></script>

        <!--Здесь мы возвращаемся к Вашему system.js. По существующим в-->
        <!--интеренете образцам и для удобства я назову его "config.js", а не "system.js"-->
        <script src="config.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--в БОДИ тоже самое, что и у Вас-->
        <app></app>
        <!--хотя импортировать app лучше в head-->
        <script>System.import('app');</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

2) файл app.ts

```
//подключаем ядро
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
//подключаем bootstrap (bootstrapper:)), через который будем выводить наше приложение
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';

//создаем компонент приложения
@Component({
    selector:'app',
    template:'<div>My first angular 2 App</div>'
})
//и сразу экспортируем его
export class App{};

//и выводим его же через бутстрэпер
//в оф документации говорят "обуваем" и типа выводим на прогулку
bootstrap(App);
```

3) и теперь файл config.js. У Вас он назывался system.js. В нем идёт как-бы описание структуры, карта всего подключаемого и расшифровка этого всего подключаемого

```
System.config({

    //указываем, что используем TypeScript
    transpiler: 'typescript',

    //настройки компилятора TypeScript
    typescriptOptions: {
        emitDecoratorMetadata: true
    },

    //map (карта) - указывает приложению где искать Ваш app.ts
    //и все другие подключаемые файлы (когда они будут)
    //В данном примере - это папка "src".
    //Т.е. мой файл "app.ts" лежит в папке "src"
    map: {
        app: "./src"
    },

    //packages определяет пакеты приложения
    //т.е. здесь мы указали что главный файл, о подключении
    //которого Вы задали главный вопрос - это "app.ts"
    //и указываем расширение поумолчанию ts(typescript)
    packages: {
        app: {
            main: './app.ts',
            defaultExtension: 'ts'
        }
    }
});
```

В заключении прилагаю ссылку на Plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/WDIDAdI9vzxsZkyLbfjt?p=preview

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ.Уже разобралась со многими вещами angular2. Очень нравится по сравнению с angular1.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Я уже давно со всем разобралась. Очень нравится angular2.